# Correlate time series with Graphite

Tags: monitoring, time-series, graphite

Does Graphite have a way to visualize correlation between two time series?

I would want somehting like this:

[image: time series correlation]

In [this SlideShare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/reyjrar/graphite-overview) there's a mention of a `correlate` data transform function (slide 11) however I can't find documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: it is not possible and would not fit Graphite's vision.

From their [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/623#issuecomment-35004908):

> If the X axis isn't time then it isn't a time series... Graphite is a graphing tool for time series data.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to displaying events in Graphite is to apply the `drawAsInfinite()` function on the red metric. This displays events as a vertical line at the time of the event.

**Update-**

Perhaps you mean `timeShift()`.

> "..what if we want to directly correlate the activity between now and
>   the same time two weeks ago? This is where the timeShift() function
>   comes in. Let's take a look at the same 4-week period, but this time
>   we'll review two weeks of current data and overlay it with a
>   time-shifted span of the two weeks prior."

[Source](http://obfuscurity.com/2012/04/Unhelpful-Graphite-Tip-10).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in the correlation of the time series, ie the blue points.

Comment: Thanks again, but what I want is a plot where the horizontal axis is not time, but a secondary dimension. For example on the plot I show, one axis is CPU usage, the other load time. This is harder to compute as it involves correlation of the two series. It turns out this doesn't fit Graphite vision and isn't possible out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Divide one by the other. The straighter that line is, the more related they are. If that correlation is linear of course. Could be logarithmic or anything. But in these cases, your two axis example wouldn’t work either.